# Django loggers setup

Tags: django, python-logging, error-logging

I've working on a Django monolith project and I've setup basic logging in my settings.py file like in the code below. It is working, I have logs folder and there 2 log files info and error.
I feel that it is not the best solution and would like to improve it and to be more advanced. Django documentation is quote confused related to the topic.

Could you share your experience and how do you setup logging on your Django projects?
Thank you in advance for any answers!

Here is my code in settings.py file:

```
# Define the log directory
LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "logs")

# Create the log directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)

FORMATTERS = (
    {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {name} {threadName} {thread:d} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {name} {funcName} {process:d} {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {name} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {funcName} {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
)

HANDLERS = {
    "console_handler": {
        "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        "formatter": "simple",
        "level": "DEBUG",
    },
    "info_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/log_info.log",
        "mode": "a",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "formatter": "verbose",
        "level": "INFO",
        "backupCount": 5,
        "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
    },
    "error_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/log_error.log",
        "mode": "a",
        "formatter": "verbose",
        "level": "WARNING",
        "backupCount": 5,
        "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
    },
}

LOGGERS = (
    {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console_handler", "info_handler"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["error_handler"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "django.server": {
            "handlers": ["error_handler"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True,
        },

    },
)
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": FORMATTERS[0],
    "handlers": HANDLERS,
    "loggers": LOGGERS[0],
}
```